# Values of ASP labels in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have an ASP.NET label control that I'm using to pass a text/string value from my C# backend to a JavaScript function inside my page.

I'm using the easyTabs feature, but need to programmatically switch tabs based on the search type.

```
function changeTab() {
        var tab = document.getElementById('<%=searchType.Text%>').textContent;
        if (tab == "Officer") {
            $('#tab-container').easytabs('select', '#tabs1-officer');
            alert("Gotten this far: 4");
        }
        else {
            $('#tab-container').easytabs('select', '#tabs1-company');
            alert("Gotten this far: 5");
        }
```

As far as I am aware, `var tab` is not getting the value from my label. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
var tab = document.getElementById('<%=searchType.ClientID %>').innerHTML;
```

Use `ClientID` to get the ID of the label, which is then used as a parameter for `getElementById`. Once you have the label, the innerHTML property will get you the text of the label.